How can I remove JSON keys?
The JSON responses I'm getting contain keys that match 'entry_id' which is redundant and not needed. The '1':, '2':, '3':, etc...
Is there any way I can remove these keys from my results, either through the fetch itself, or some manipulation afterwards?
Fetch:
async function getEntries(){
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${username}:${password}`)}`
        }
      })
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
};

Response:
{
  '1': {
    entry_id: '1',
    user_id: '0',
    date_created: '2023-09-21 16:17:10',
    value: 'text',
  },
  '2': {
    entry_id: '2',
    user_id: '0',
    date_created: '2023-09-27 15:57:43',
    value: 'text',
  },
  '3': {
    entry_id: '3',
    user_id: '0',
    date_created: '2023-09-29 20:21:33',
    value: 'text',
  }
}


I think I understand what you want, but JSON doesn't have "headers" — what you are receiving is an object with three members; those three members are named '1', '2', and '3' each of which is an object.  After receiving this you could process the json into an array of three objects which would, in effect, remove the "headers"

@StephenP yes that's exactly what I meant, I've updated the question with 'keys'. Thank you!

Note that one benefit of the 1/2/3 keys is constant time access to the data associated with any given key, regardless of the apparent ordering of entries.

Json doesn't have headers, you can call these as keys. Try the code below. you will get the list of objects and keys. You can use Object.values(json). '1','2','3' will be removed. See the example below
const data = {
  '1': {
    entry_id: '1',
    user_id: '0',
    date_created: '2023-09-21 16:17:10',
    value: 'text',
  },
  '2': {
    entry_id: '2',
    user_id: '0',
    date_created: '2023-09-27 15:57:43',
    value: 'text',
  },
  '3': {
    entry_id: '3',
    user_id: '0',
    date_created: '2023-09-29 20:21:33',
    value: 'text',
  }
}

const dataList = Object.values(data);
//You can use dataList as normal object array

// Output the modified JSON data
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataList));

Output
[

{"entry_id":"1","user_id":"0","date_created":"2023-09-21 16:17:10","value":"text"},

{"entry_id":"2","user_id":"0","date_created":"2023-09-27 15:57:43","value":"text"},

{"entry_id":"3","user_id":"0","date_created":"2023-09-29 20:21:33","value":"text"}

]

